# Java - When designing a JFrame that will have a Canvas,

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, java-2d

After calling a method with these two lines of code:

```
final Graphics canvasGraphics = screenCanvas.getGraphics();
canvasGraphics.fill3DRect(rectangleX, rectangleY, 500, 100, true);
```

The rectangle flashes when the program runs, and then disappears. However, when I put this same line in an anonymous inner class with my MouseListener:

```
screenCanvas.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter(){

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event){
        canvasGraphics.fill3DRect(rectangleX, rectangleY, 500, 100, true);
    }
}
```

The rectangle stays there. What is causing this behavior?

Comment: `screenCanvas.getGraphics();` - Don't do this. Create a `JPanel`, override it's `paintComponent` method, call `super.paintComponent(g)` inside and do your custom drawing there.

Comment: So should I call drawPanel.paintComponent(screenCanvas.getGraphics()) where drawPanel is the overwritten JPanel?

Comment: No, you should perform all painting inside the `paintComponent` method (you only need one panel) - No `getGraphics()` needed. Check out [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for a full tutorial. Btw, I think the reason why the rectangle stays in your second snippet is because the `RepaintManager` doesn't automatically repaint the frame, so this way the rectangle stays there for a while. (Note how it also disappears when you resize the frame)

Comment: Thank you so much, that really helps.

Comment: The only reason to use a java.awt.Canvas is because you want to take direct control over the painting process

Comment: Swing and AWT/Canvas can have different painting process, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35402007/having-issues-with-displays/35402391#35402391) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175174/paintcomponent-vs-paint-and-jpanel-vs-canvas-in-a-paintbrush-type-gui/12175819#12175819) for some details

Comment: If you want to use `java.awt.Canvas`, then you should be be using a [`BufferStrategy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) and [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html)

Comment: You might also want to have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Answer (score 0):

first you have to know that the `Graphics` of a JComponent is changed (repainted) on every change (resizing, minimizing, moving ...), and this happen inside the method `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)`.

in the first scenario the two lines of code are executed just once and they have an effect (you noticed the flash), but the the Component is painted very often on every change, so when launching your application the `canvasGraphics` is filled by the two lines of code, but just after that the method `paintComponent` is called , so it repaints the `Graphics` again and you changes are lost.

in the second scenario you are not drawing on the `Graphics` directly, the `Graphics` is changed once the mouse is clicked so the `paintComponent` get executed when the program launches and the window is shown, once the mouse is Pressed inside the Canvas your reimplemented method is called and the `Graphics` is changed but this time the `paintComponent` method will not ommit your changes because nothing is happening to the element.

a solution is to reimplement the `paintComponent` method on the wanted element to be sure that your changes is performed each time the elements get repainted.

Comment: `JFrame` doesn't have a `paintComponent` method